# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when uploading text

Tags: php, mysql, text

I've created a text upload function. When I try to post a text to the database an error just says: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". My code looks like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['body']) && strlen($_REQUEST['name']) > 0 && strlen($_REQUEST['body']) > 0) {
    //get data
    $title = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];

    mysql_connect("Server","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    //insert data
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($body)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')") or die(mysql_error());

    die("Your text has been posted!");
?>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What's the structure of the table `news`?

Comment: id - int(11)  title - varchar(100)   body - varchar(1000)

Comment: you need to add field before values in query

Answer (score 0):

Your are inserting less or more fields than the actual number of fields in your table. To prevent such errors it's always a good practice to explicitly indicate in the sql the fields you are inserting into. Like this:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news(field1, field2, field3) VALUES (...
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nelson said - you're writing the wrong fields. Your table is structured:

```
id - int(11) title - varchar(100) body - varchar(1000)
```

You're adding:

```
id - ''
title - '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."'
body - '".mysql_real_escape_string($body)."' 
date - '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."'
```

You need to add a date field to your table, or drop it from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

But remember add you field name **(field1, field2, field3)** in you insert query.

Set **primary key** with **auto increment** id field in database table.

```
<?php


$mytitle = $_REQUEST['name'];
$mybody = $_REQUEST['body'];


if (isset($mytitle) &&  strlen($mytitle) > 0  && isset($mybody) && strlen($mybody) > 0) {
    //get data


    mysql_connect("Server","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    //insert data
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($mytitle)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($mybody)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')") or die(mysql_error());

    die("Your text has been posted!");
}    
?>
```